# Get All subscriptions per tenant in azure

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

I want to have a Logic App that gets per tenant all its subscriptions.
I understand that there is a rest API for that purpose:
`GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01`
as mentioned in the [Subscriptions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions/list) documentation.

Two questions:

1. Where do I specify here for which tenant I want to get the list of subscriptions?
2. I understand that I need a token in order to get this data, but how do I get this token and from where exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states in the documentation you linked to, the API call uses the Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow. This means it will get the subscriptions from the logged in user's tenant.

However, there's a Logic App connector to connect to Azure Resource Manager. And that connector has an action called List subscriptions.

[image: List subscriptions action]

When you add it, you create a service connection to Azure by logging in, which can be used for subsequent requests.

This sample implementation does the trick: it gets the subscriptions and returns them from the Logic App.

[image: Logic App getting subscriptions]